# How do I create a "report" to determine if code from old commits still exist in master branch?

Tags: git

I have a list of commits hashes from an old contributor, made years ago, to my git repository hosted on GitHub. I would like to run a "report" of some sort that would let me determine what code from the commits that this person made still exists in my current master branch. The codebase as a whole has evolved over the years greatly and I anticipate that a lot of the originally contributed code would have been modified, deleted, or moved since their original contribution.

I originally thought that I could use `git diff` or GitHub's compare tools to figure this out, however, those will give a comparison of the entire repository between commit hashes which is not helpful with this goal.

Comment: you might try `git revert --no-commit` on each revision. If you can revert it, then code is still there.... but it's not a bullet-proof approach. Code might have been adjusted and you might get lots of false alarms.

Comment: You may need to better define what "still exists" means. Suppose the person added a line to a file, and later someone changed 1 character in that line. Is that a match? What if someone changed all but 1 character in that line, is it still a match?

Comment: As you mentioned, "modified, deleted, or moved" are possibilities. I would add "copied" to the list as well. Other than deleted, which may be easy-ish to identify as described in @eftshift0's comment, the others are hard to quantify without a good definition of what you're calling a "match".

Comment: `git blame` can give you any lines from the original contributor that have survived till now. But it works only on lines that are entirely unchanged. As others commented, it'll be difficult to sort through partially changed lines. I suspect that would have to be a manual process.